# Review queue should be ordered by oldest first

Tags: discussion, documentation

**Opinion:**

The review queue should be ordered by oldest suggested edit first. Right now it shows the lastest ones at the top.

[image]

I've had contributions waiting for approval for many hours because it's on the last page. Recent suggested edits have a higher chance of being reviewed.

I even had one case where my suggested edit was declined after 3 hours, because a duplicate entry made 2 hours later was reviewed and approved before mine did.

While it's not a big deal, since you can edit any topic at any time, it still feels sort of flawed. I assume it's a super-easy fix as well so I hope this gets looked into.

Comment: Definitly. Old posts remain overseen. I've noticed some proposed changes that are older then a week and got stuck at page 3 or 4.